# How can I get the longitude and latitude of a specified pixel (e.g. equal to certain value) with Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, latitude-longitude, pixel

I want to get the longitude and latitude of a specified pixel (e.g. equal to a certain value) using Google Earth Engine. In other words, I have used "ee.Reducer.min()" to get the minimum value of a certain region. Now I want to know the position of the pixel with minimum value.

```
//import data
var eramon = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR")
          .filterDate("2022-01-01","2023-01-01")
          .select(["temperature_2m"])
          .first()
          .clip(region);

//add LonLat values
var eramon_LonLat = eramon.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat());

//get minimum temperature value of region of interest
var min = eramon_LonLat.select(["temperature_2m"])
                       .reduceRegion({
                        reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),   
                        geometry: region,
                        scale: 11132});
var min_LonLat = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the numInputs option on the min reducer.  That will cause it to carry along that many additional values from the min location:

```
var min = eramon_LonLat.reduceRegion({
                        reducer: ee.Reducer.min(3),   
                        geometry: region,
                        scale: 11132});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is an effective solution!